# Is there any google correlate API that I can refer to?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to include google correlate into my application using Python but I require its API to do so. Please help me where to look at or share me some insights about it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Google correlate data is valid up till 2017 March, not sure if it's deprecated but it definitely won't be useful if you're after up-to-date correlations